# How do I add real-time analytics to my Q or A on SO?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard

Is it possible to add some sort of tracking or live analytics to the questions or answers I post here on Stack Overflow?

Bottom line: is it possible to add Analytics to a page that is not ours?

**Note that this topic hasn't been removed because the information can be usefull for other usecases.**

Comment: Just a heads-up: this post and the general behaviour of adding image beacons to posts is [being discussed on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231608/is-it-appropriate-to-add-third-party-tracking-scripts-to-individual-questions-an).

Comment: This violates the [Stack Exchange terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), section 3(e): *Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that ... (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information*. Collecting data with a hidden 1 pixel image is not appropriate.

Comment: It's also a little suspicious when the Dropbox image you include in your answer is titled "SO Virus Proof of Concept" ...

Comment: It's just a screenshot with the Google Analytics page that proofed that in that date I tracked a SE question. See my edit, I wasn't informed about the situation and didn't consider that as it's live data and I wasn't able to save it that it would be considered a violation of terms of service by "expropriation of data". But still It's a nice information to keep on the site, as it can be used with other applicability.

Comment: @CMPSoares Note that I'm not talking about the quality of the content; I simply stated that naming an image "SO Virus Proof of Concept" is suspicious when, network-wide, you're silently collecting information from users without their consent. Also note that you should remove the tracking beacons from your profile pages as well.

Comment: @JohnBensin I'm working on it, I named it that because of the following [question on the Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252749/virus-introduced-in-a-question). Because I started it first as being an concern for safety, when everyone said I was being to paranoid I started using it as addition to the normal stats to improve the popular questions. Totally forgot to read terms of service about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is! Using an [image beacon](https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon) created primarily to [track live github pages](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-beacon-image-github-website-email-analytics/).

It's really simple, just follow the steps:

#### Setup instructions:

First, log in to your Google Analytics account (if you don't have an Analytics account yet, get one [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/)) and [set up a new property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en):

- Select "Website", use new "Universal Analytics" tracking
- **Website name:** anything you want (e.g. StackOverflow Questions and Answers)
- **WebSite URL: `https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/`**
- Click "Get Tracking ID", copy the `UA-XXXXX-X` ID on next page

Next, add a tracking image to the questions/answers pages you want to track:

- `https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/UA-XXXXX-X/accounttype/question_name`
- `UA-XXXXX-X` should be your tracking ID
- `accounttype/question_name` is an arbitrary path.

Add this image to your question/answer (if you have both in the same page, choose only one), and you're ready!

#### Example used for this page:

```
    ![Beacon][1]
    
    [1]: https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/UA-50149210-2/StackOverflow/How_do_I_add_real-time_analytics_to_my_Q_or_A_on_SO_question?pixel
```

Once everything is setup, install [this custom dashboard](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=MQS4cmZdSh2OWUVqRntqXQ) in your account for a nice real-time overview (as shown in screenshot below).

#### Result:

[image: example dashboard]

## Edit 14-05-2014:

After it [being discussed at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231608/is-it-appropriate-to-add-third-party-tracking-scripts-to-individual-questions-an), I should add the detail to this answer that the use of this beacon or anything similar, might be subject of approval by the terms of service of the targeted website.

In the case of SE, it violates [the Stack Exchange terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), section 3(e): *Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that ... (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information.*